# How to fix Mine Craft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I got Minecraft and I logged in, and I pressed the play button. It started to download, but when its almost done, the text appears in the download bar "downloading twitch-external-platform-4.5-native-windows-64.jar" can someone please tell what that means and how I can fix it.

Comment: I believe it is simply informing you that it is download that file. That file is a library file that is likely necessary to launch and play the game. Given the title of the file, I would say it is for Twitch streaming integration

Comment: Is there a problem that occurs with the download, like the launcher crashing or something?  The way the launcher is set up now, you click "Play" and it will check to see if you have the selected version of Minecraft installed (default is always latest version).  If it is not found, the launcher will download the files and install it for you.  One that finishes, the game should start up automatically.

Answer (score 7):

This means that Minecraft is getting stuck at downloading the library file that allows for integrated Twitch streaming. This is somewhat odd, because it's downloaded from the same place as all of the other game libraries (although it may be that this is the first one it attempts to download).

If you have a slow connection, it may just be that it is taking a while to download (it is a ~7MB file). You may want to leave the launcher running for a while, or wait a few hours or a day and try again.

You could also try downloading the file manually from:

https://libraries.minecraft.net/tv/twitch/twitch-external-platform/4.5/twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar

And placing it in this folder:

```
%appdata%\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\
```

If that folder does not exist, try creating it.